# fabric produce some errors on XCTest

Tags: ios, crashlytics, xctest, google-fabric

I try to make a XCTest.
My app uses fabric and crashlytics.
then
My app can be built.
But XCTest produces some errors when XCTest build.

Here is error capture.
[image]

What is this problem?

Comment: Which target are you building ?

Comment: XCTest target. when XCTest target,this error happens.

Comment: I have the same problem with my tests. I do not use crashlytics or fabric, it just worked one day and the next it was not working anymore. Maybe an XCode issue?

Comment: I think it is fabric or crashlytics’s problem.